# custom label on select as floating

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to create a floating label select component, So the select box will have a label on click of that it will show a dropdown options. Like [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-7emsrv?file=index.js) With an icon and override the native browser options.

I was able to achieve using input field, but i am not able to understand how to create such a like component.

Dropdown.js

```
import React from "react";
import {
  DropdownWrapper,
  StyledSelect,
  StyledOption,
  StyledLabel
} from "./style";

export function Dropdown(props) {
  return (
    <DropdownWrapper onChange={props.onChange}>
      <StyledLabel htmlFor={props.id}>{props.formLabel}</StyledLabel>
      <StyledSelect id={props.id} name={props.id}>
        {props.children}
      </StyledSelect>
    </DropdownWrapper>
  );
}

export function Option(props) {
  return <StyledOption selected={props.selected}>{props.value}</StyledOption>;
}
```

Style.js

```
import styled from "@emotion/styled";

export const DropdownWrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
`;

export const StyledSelect = styled.select`
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  text-indent: 1px;
  text-overflow: "";
`;

export const StyledOption = styled.option`
  color: ${(props) => (props.selected ? "lightgrey" : "black")};
`;

export const StyledLabel = styled.label`
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
`;
```

Any help appreciated, here is what i have tried so far. [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-dream-fub9y)